# Calculate integral $\int_0^1 e^{e^{e^x}} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have to calculate integral $$\Large \int_0^1 e^{e^{e^x}} dx$$

Is this even possible?

Comment: You *have to*? Why? What's the context?

Comment: It's an exercise in my calculus exercise book

Comment: It's obviously Riemann-integrable since fucntion is continuous..

Comment: And as we see from the edits, the function grows rapidly ;)

Comment: I wanted to make it more clear, since default latex was too small..

Comment: Being obviously integrable doesn't mean it has a nice analytic form

Comment: ^ I know that, so Im just asking if we can do anything about it.

Comment: I would be quite surprised if this had an elementary closed form, however it can be computed [numerically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5Ee%5Ee%5Ex%2C+x%3D+0..1).

Comment: It depends on whether you interpret $\Large a^{b^{c^d}}$ as $((a^b)^c)^d$ or $a^{(b^{(c^d)})}.$  In one interpretation, you're just integrating an exponential function with a weird looking base.  In the other interpretation, I don't think it's humanly possible.  I tried it in two different computer programs, and each used a different interpretation.

Comment: Unfortunately, its the second interpretation.

Comment: We know that the simpler case $e^{e^x}$ doesn't have an elementary antiderivative ([see this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html)).

Comment: Using mathematica for $100$ decimal places its value is $102797.7143200124685248018640170538279377919481376920636815170937595170002074613733938211750473699092.$

Comment: If you are interested in trying to prove that no antiderivative exist you can try to apply [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). See also [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral).

Comment: Is it possible to bound this integral by sth? And have approximation?

Comment: @luka5z : You can eventually use some high order Taylor expension I guess (but like, really high).

Comment: i suppose you need to establish the relation between $\int_0^1e^x{\rm d}x , \int_0^1e^{e^x}{\rm d}x$ and others, in that case you don't even need to evaluate anything!

Comment: See also [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take $u = e^{e^x}$. Thus, $ du = ue^x dx \implies dx = \frac{1}{u \text{log}(u)}du.$ Hence,

$$\int_{0}^{1} e^{e^{e^x}}\,dx = \int_{e}^{e^e} \frac{e^{u}}{u \text{log}(u) }\,du. $$By expanding in Taylor

$$\frac{e^{u}}{u \text{log}(u)}= \frac{1}{u\text{log}(u)}+ \frac{1}{\text{log}(u)}+\frac{u}{2!\cdot\text{log}(u)} + \frac{u^2}{3! \cdot\text{log}(u)}+ \mathcal{O}(u^3).$$ Hence,

$$\int  \frac{e^{u}}{u \text{log}(u)}\,du = C + \text{log}\left(\text{log}(u)\right) +\sum \limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\cdot\text{Ei}\left((n+1)\text{log}(u)\right),$$ where $\text{Ei}$ is the exponetial integral given by $$ \text{Ei}(x) = -\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,dt,$$ which is not an elementary function according to Risch algorithm.

Comment: This post was vandalised; I rolled it back

Comment: @preferred_anon, thanks!

Comment: Going back to $x$ makes it a little more digestible $$\int e^{e^{e^x}} \, dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\text{Ei}\left((n+1) e^x\right)}{(n+1)!}+x+C$$

Comment: @AlexSilva Why did you [approve](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1477348) the edit?

Comment: Don't remember exactly. Long time ago. I think the answer had been vandalized.